# How to reset to initial state after using filter() on an array in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a React app that renders a grid of cards displaying local restaurants. Card data is stored in a JSON file and the cards are filtered by cuisine category. All restaurant categories are displayed by default in the  component.

The problem I'm running into is on the first selection, e.g. "Asian" the cards are filtered correctly, but on the second selection, e.g. "American", the array returns empty.

I've created a function to reset the component to it's initial state, and this works as expected and can be implemented by clicking "All Restaurants". I know that React batches updates to state, so I can't figure out a way to reset to my restaurantData object before filtering a new restaurant.

I come from a design background and am fairly new to React and JavaScript. I've tried implementing the state reset in tandem in the onClick function as well as in my filtering methods, but no luck.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import { Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import RestaurantList from "../components/RestaurantList";
import restaurants from "../data/restaurantData.json";


const INITIAL_STATE = {
  restaurants: restaurants
}

class Restaurants extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        restaurants: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(() => ({ restaurants: restaurants}));

}

render() {    
  let restaurants = this.state.restaurants;

let onResetArray = () => {
  this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
  console.log(restaurants)
}

let filterMexican = () => {
  const mexicanRestaurants = restaurants.filter( restaurant => restaurant.category === "mexican");
  this.setState({restaurants: mexicanRestaurants});
  console.log(mexicanRestaurants);
}

let filterBreakfast = () => {
  const breakfastRestaurants = restaurants.filter( restaurant => restaurant.category === "breakfast");
  this.setState({restaurants: breakfastRestaurants});
  console.log(breakfastRestaurants);
}

let filterAsian = () => {
    const asianRestaurants = restaurants.filter( restaurant => restaurant.category === "asian");
    this.setState({restaurants: asianRestaurants});
    console.log(asianRestaurants);
}

let filterAmerican = () => {
  const americanRestaurants = restaurants.filter( restaurant => restaurant.category === "american");
  this.setState({restaurants: americanRestaurants});
  console.log(americanRestaurants);
}



     return (
       <div>
         <Navbar />
         <div className="container-fluid my-4">
           <h1 className="page-title my-4">Restaurants</h1>
           <Nav
             className="justify-content-center mb-4"
             variant="pills"
             defaultActiveKey="restaurants"
           >
             <Nav.Item>
               <Nav.Link eventKey="restaurants" onClick={onResetArray}>
                 All Restaurants
               </Nav.Link>
             </Nav.Item>
             <Nav.Item>
               <Nav.Link
                 eventKey="mexican-restaurants"
                 id="mexican-button"
                 onClick={ () => { onResetArray(restaurants); filterMexican() } }
               >
                 Mexican
               </Nav.Link>
             </Nav.Item>
             <Nav.Item>
               <Nav.Link
                 eventKey="asian-restaurants"
                 onClick={ () => { onResetArray(restaurants); filterAsian() }}
               >
                 Asian
               </Nav.Link>
             </Nav.Item>
             <Nav.Item>
               <Nav.Link
                 eventKey="american-restaurants"
                 onClick={filterAmerican}
               >
                 American
               </Nav.Link>
             </Nav.Item>
             <Nav.Item>
               <Nav.Link
                 eventKey="breakfast-restaurants"
                 onClick={filterBreakfast}
               >
                 Breakfast
               </Nav.Link>
             </Nav.Item>
           </Nav>

           <RestaurantList restaurants={this.state.restaurants} />

         </div>
         <Footer />
       </div>
     );
  }
}

export default Restaurants;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different names for global and local variables. and change code accordingly.

```
import allRestaurants from "../data/restaurantData.json";
```